# DataTables, filter multiple columns with multiple values

Tags: jquery, datatables

The [following page](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) gives an example on how to implement a filter by values on columns.

I want to replace the `select` with a `multiple select`, so user can filter out more than one value for a specific column, however, I am unsure on how to process the multiple values received by the `multiple select`.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns().every( function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select multiple><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        } );

                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    } );
                } );
            }
        } );
    } );
```

Specifically I would need to know what to do here when `this` is a multiple select.

```
var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
    $(this).val()
);

column
    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
    .draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the site:

> Match words out of order. For example if you search for Allan Fife it would
>   match a row containing the words Allan and Fife, regardless of the order or 
>   position that they appear in the table.

You might be better off using filter() instead of search() depending on what you want to do.

in your
    $(this).val()
the values should be returned in some type of array or list. check the data and see what it looks like, and handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [this](https://github.com/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter) DataTables plug-in, it provides 'multiple-column-multiple-criteria' filtering (including union selection across multiple columns).

Here is the brief working **DEMO**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 //Source data definition 
 var tableData = [
    {item: 'banana', category: 'fruit', color: 'yellow'},
    {item: 'pear', category: 'fruit', color: 'green'},
    {item: 'cabbage', category: 'vegie', color: 'green'},
    {item: 'carrot', category: 'vegie', color: 'red'},
    {item: 'apple', category: 'fruit', color: 'red'},
    {item: 'kiwi', category: 'fruit', color: 'brown'}
 ];
 //DataTable definition 
 window.dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
   sDom: 'tF',
   data: tableData,
   columns: [{
     data: 'item',
     title: 'Item'
    }, {
     data: 'category',
     title: 'Category'
    }, {
     data: 'color',
     title: 'Color'
  
   }]
 });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/js/mfilter.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/css/mfilter.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting but your example probably doesn't work properly, there are no column filtering elements.

Comment: Buttons with filter icons are filtering elements, you click those, you get drop down menu with the necessary features.